# How to create an editable table (by users) from Webform submission data?

Tags: users, webforms

I'm using D7 and creating a system to manage information about a specific game's characters. I have been advised to use webforms to collect the data from the character's, and I want the user that fills out those webforms be able to edit the data, just like they would on an Excel table.

I've been looking and looking and haven't been able to find an answer to how to get it done.

Any help?

Comment: You might be able to custom composite element, which does create an editable table. Please note custom composite elements have some limitations include no support for file uploads or multiple value elements (ie checkboxes)

Comment: Custom composite elements are only supported by the Webform module for Drupal 8.  I am not sure which version you are using.

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7. I haven't answered this yet, because i was playing around with Editable modules, not sure which one at this point :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews)

[image]

[Drupal Editable Views demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_D4z4Bw6iw)

Comment: This is the one I've tried first, and despite being able to create an Editable Table with the Webform Submission Data, divided by components, I still haven't figured out how to make them editable.

Comment: `I still haven't figured out how to make them editable` @BBandeira Did you watch the demo video that I linked to in my answer?

Comment: I did, and it works with Content Types, and has no reference how to use Webforms.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Editable Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields)

[image]

[How To Edit Fields On Node's Display And Within Views (Drupal Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf_2e_RYS2M)

Comment: Am going to give this a try. Does this work with webform submission data?

Comment: @BBandeira I've never tried it with webform data, good luck, I hope it still works :)

Comment: I did try. Doesn't work :) The struggle continues.
Thanks for the input, though.